# Satanama Mantra and Hinduism?

Tags: yoga, kriyayoga

I read about Satanama ( स त न म)  Mantra which is part of kirtan kriya and was popularized in the West by Yogi Bhajan.

Is this part of Sanatan Dharma or has any referral to any type of Hindu Gods?

Comment: Are you talking about this https://www.yogapedia.com/definition/10781/sa-ta-na-ma?

Comment: yes what I found online at least. I heard about this but not sure if connected with Hinduism or else